# php and json reading string

Tags: php, json

I have problem to read json response using pvp from http://www.wunderground.com/ API. What I found is there is a problem with reading anything else but integer. I  was looking in internet but there was no suitable answer for my problem. Finally i gave up...

the code:

```
$json_string = file_get_contents($w);
$json_string = utf8_encode($json_string);
$result = json_decode($json_string,true);
```

the result of `print_r($result);` gives me full proper answer

```
Array ( [response] => Array ( [version] (...) Europe/Warsaw [local_tz_offset] => +0100 [weather] => Scattered Clouds [temperature_string] => 30 F (-1 C) [temp_f] => 30 [temp_c] => -1 [relative_humidity] => 93% [wind_string] => From the SE at 8 MPH [wind_dir] => SE [wind_degrees] => 130 [wind_mph] => 8 [wind_gust_mph] => 0 [wind_kph] => 13 [wind_gust_kph] => 0 [pressure_mb] => 1013 [pressure_in] => 29.92 [pressure_trend] => 0 [dewpoint_string] => 28 F (-2 C) [dewpoint_f] => 28 [dewpoint_c] => -2 [heat_index_string] => NA [heat_index_f] => NA [heat_index_c] => NA [windchill_string] => 23 F (-5 C) [windchill_f] => 23 [windchill_c] => -5 [feelslike_string] => 23 F (-5 C) [feelslike_f] => 23 [feelslike_c] => -5 [visibility_mi] => 6.2 [visibility_km] => 10.0 [solarradiation] => [UV] => 1 [precip_1hr_string] => -9999.00 in (-9999.00 mm) [precip_1hr_in] => -9999.00 [precip_1hr_metric] => -9999.00 [precip_today_string] => 0.00 in (0.0 mm) [precip_today_in] => 0.00 [precip_today_metric] => 0.0 [icon] => partlycloudy [icon_url] => (..) [forecast_url] =>(..) [history_url] => (..) [ob_url] =>(..)52.16999817,20.96999931 ) )
```

But the point is i can read only Integer but not string dunno why :

```
echo "Current temperature in ${location} is: ${temp_c}\n";
echo "Current temperature F in ${location} is: ${temp_f}\n";
echo "Current humidity F in ${location} is: ${hum}\n";
echo "Current wind in ${location} is: ${wind}\n";
```

The output looks like below :

```
Current temperature in Warsaw is: -3 
Current temperature F in Warsaw is: 27 
Current humidity F in Warsaw is: 
Current wind in Warsaw is:
```

So as i mentioned earlier I can not read anything from json but integer.
Using php version :

```
php -v
PHP 5.3.6 (cli) (built: Apr 14 2011 14:58:35)
Copyright (c) 1997-2011 The PHP Group
Zend Engine v2.3.0, Copyright (c) 1998-2011 Zend Technologies
```

After spending several hours looking for solution still couldn't find answer for my problem.
If you know any clue please let me know 'cause now I'm stuck with this problem I think forever.

```
var_dump($result)
```

gives me as well proper array :

```
 array(3) { ["response"] (...)["weather"]=> string(16) "Scattered Clouds" ["temperature_string"]=> string(11) "30 F (-1 C)" ["temp_f"]=> int(30) ["temp_c"]=> int(-1) ["relative_humidity"]=> string(3) "93%" ["wind_string"]=> string(20) "From the SE at 8 MPH" ["wind_dir"]=> string(2) "SE" ["wind_degrees"]=> int(130) ["wind_mph"]=> int(8) ["wind_gust_mph"]=> int(0) ["wind_kph"]=> int(13) ["wind_gust_kph"]=> int(0) ["pressure_mb"]=> string(4) "1013" ["pressure_in"]=> string(5) "29.92" ["pressure_trend"]=> string(1) "0" ["dewpoint_string"]=> string(11) "28 F (-2 C)" ["dewpoint_f"]=> int(28) ["dewpoint_c"]=> int(-2) ["heat_index_string"]=> string(2) "NA" ["heat_index_f"]=> string(2) "NA" ["heat_index_c"]=> string(2) "NA" ["windchill_string"]=> string(11) "23 F (-5 C)" ["windchill_f"]=> string(2) "23" ["windchill_c"]=> string(2) "-5" ["feelslike_string"]=> string(11) "23 F (-5 C)" ["feelslike_f"]=> string(2) "23" ["feelslike_c"]=> string(2) "-5" ["visibility_mi"]=> string(3) "6.2" ["visibility_km"]=> string(4) "10.0" ["solarradiation"]=> string(0) "" ["UV"]=> string(1) "1" ["precip_1hr_string"]=> string(25) "-9999.00 in (-9999.00 mm)" ["precip_1hr_in"]=> string(8) "-9999.00" ["precip_1hr_metric"]=> string(8) "-9999.00" ["precip_today_string"]=> string(16) "0.00 in (0.0 mm)" ["precip_today_in"]=> string(4) "0.00" ["precip_today_metric"]=> string(3) "0.0" ["icon"]=> string(12) "partlycloudy" ["icon_url"]=> string(47) "http://icons-ak.wxug.com/i/c/k/partlycloudy.gif" ["forecast_url"]=> string(54) (..) ["history_url"]=> string(76) (..) ["ob_url"]=> string(89) (...) } }
```

P.S i have a bit problems with pasting and formatting all print_r result so i had to cout out a bit with '(..)'

Thanks

Comment: Can you provide the code that takes `$result` and adds it's data to the new variables in the second block?

Comment: Please, could you paste us the return of var_dump($result)

Comment: Can you please paste the json response.

Comment: here is full response using var_dump:     http://amkd.net/ip/ip.php  plus last line's i have added 'Current temperature in Warsaw is: 0 Current temperature F in Warsaw is: 32 Current humidity F in Warsaw is: Current wind in Warsaw is:'

Comment: Here is pure json response:  http://amkd.net/ip/json.php  thanks